# how to read from file without using namespace std

Tags: c++, file, std

I have a question regarding how to read from file if I don't write 'using namespace std'. I know that if you read from input you write std::cin, but what about files? I have ifstream f("file.in"); and std::f doesn't work. How do I read in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that's in the namespace `std` is the *type*:

```
std::ifstream f("file.in");
//^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The name `f` is in whatever namespace where the above line appears.